# Firebase Auth JWT Google provider have two user serial when decode jwt

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, jwt, google-signin

Why does my Firebase Auth JWT decoding result contain more than one user information for a single provider when logging in with Google through Firebase Auth.

```
{
  "iss": "",
  "aud": "-",
  "auth_time": "",
  "user_id": "",
  "sub": "",
  "iat": 1698251030,
  "exp": 1698254630,
  "firebase": {
    "identities": {
      "google.com": [
        "bbbbb",
        "aaaaa"
      ]
    },
    "sign_in_provider": "google.com"
  }
}
```

I don't know how it happens, and I'm not sure about the cause